# Setting up a second Rails app locally with PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, postgresapp

I already have a Rails app, successfully working with Postgres.app.

I don't even remember what I did to get the first database created and connected to Rails, but it works and this is what I have in `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: gnossy_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

---

Now for my second Rails app I've created the app with

`rails new my_app --database=postgresql --skip-test-unit`

And Rails created this for me in database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development
```

**What would I need to do, to get my second app connected with a PG db?**

`rake db:create:all` results in `"FATAL:  role "my_app" does not exist"`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a postgres error.

```
"FATAL:  role "my_app" does not exist"
```

When you run migrations the app tries to log into the database to perform the migrations.

This error is telling you that in the database you don't have a role called "my_app"

If you would like to check if this is true log into your postgres database:

From console:

```
psql
```

Once you are in, check your roles:

```
\du
```

This command will return a relation of your roles with their permissions.

To fix this in your rails app try adding user and password credentials with PG permissions to **database.yml**

```
username: your_user
password: your_pasword
```

Comment: As you can see from my provided `database.yml` for my first app, no username/password seems to be used there. Would I still need that for my second app?

Comment: At the moment your Rails application is trying to connect to the database with user **my_app**. I guess that you don't have my_app user or most probably `my_user` doesn't have permissions for your new database but has for `gnossy_development`